# VHDL: How to solve array lengths mismatch Fatal (vsim-3714) error correctly?

Tags: arrays, range, constants, vhdl

**The problem** - mismatch between the constrained range of the target signal and ranges of the constants being conditionally assigned to it.

I'm new to VHDL and this is my first large scale development project using this language.
I've written the code that assigns one of the constants of the custom `unconstrained array` type to the signal of the same type based on the value of the incoming ID byte. Each of the constants is of its own range and these ranges are not necessarily the same. The code is successfully compiled with no errors or warnings. However, attempt to simulate it generates the following error.

```
Fatal: (vsim-3714) At array depth 1, array lengths do not match. Left is 5 (0 to 4). Right is 4 (0 to 3).
Time: 100 us  Iteration: 0  Process: /active_set/line__41 File: C:/...ProjectPath.../Active_Set.vhd
Fatal error in Architecture Behavioral at C:/...Project.../Active_Set.vhd line 41
```

The MRE code is provided below with problematic line identified as such.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Active_Set is

    Port( ID : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
         );

end entity;


Architecture Behavioral of Active_Set is

type t_CMD_SET is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

constant SET_10h : t_CMD_SET := (x"11", x"12", x"13", x"14");
constant SET_20h : t_CMD_SET := (x"21", x"22", x"23", x"24", x"25");
constant SET_DUMMY : t_CMD_SET := (x"00", x"00", x"00", x"00", x"00");

function f_ACT_SET (ID   : std_logic_vector;
                    SET1 : t_CMD_SET;
                    SET2 : t_CMD_SET;
                    SET3 : t_CMD_SET
                    )
                        return t_CMD_SET is
begin
        if    ID = x"10" then
              return SET1;
        elsif ID = x"20" then
              return SET2;      
        else
              return SET3;
        end if;
end function;

signal ACT_SET   : t_CMD_SET(0 to 4);
    
begin
-- NEXT LINE IS PROBLEMATIC, LINE 41
ACT_SET   <= f_ACT_SET(ID, SET_10h, SET_20h, SET_DUMMY);

end Behavioral;
```

The respective .do file I've used to simulate the code above in Modelsim is provided below.

```
onerror {resume}
quietly WaveActivateNextPane {} 0
add wave -noupdate -radix hexadecimal /active_set/ID
add wave -noupdate -radix hexadecimal /active_set/ACT_SET
TreeUpdate [SetDefaultTree]
WaveRestoreCursors {{Cursor 1} {0000000 ps} 0}
quietly wave cursor active 1
configure wave -namecolwidth 270
configure wave -valuecolwidth 70
configure wave -justifyvalue left
configure wave -signalnamewidth 0
configure wave -snapdistance 10
configure wave -datasetprefix 0
configure wave -rowmargin 4
configure wave -childrowmargin 2
configure wave -gridoffset 0
configure wave -gridperiod 1
configure wave -griddelta 40
configure wave -timeline 0
configure wave -timelineunits us
update
WaveRestoreZoom {0 ps} {210 us}
view wave 
wave clipboard store
wave create -driver freeze -pattern repeater -initialvalue 00000000 -period 100us -sequence { 00000000 00010000 00100000 00000000  } -repeat 1 -range 7 0 -starttime 0us -endtime 400us sim:/active_set/ID 
WaveExpandAll -1
WaveCollapseAll -1
wave clipboard restore
```

While it seems easy to fix the problem by padding each smaller range constant with trailing x"00" to match the size of the largest constant, i.e., `constant SET_10h : t_CMD_SET := (x"11", x"12", x"13", x"14", x"00")`, it's unacceptable for the variety of reasons. First, it's a brut-force approach that beats the purpose of using unconstrained array in the first place. Second, the number of constants could be quite large and their ranges may differ drastically, making any future code maintenance very difficult. The questions are below.

1. Is there any other way to resolve this error that wouldn't require padding the constants to the same size? Please note that current Language Syntax option is set to "Use 1076-2002" and changing it to -2008 is not the first choice as the remainder of the project is using -2002 option.
2. Is there any way to avoid having 'else' choice SET3 at all? It just doesn't sound right to create an extra dummy array for invalid ID values. I'm sure it's possible but being a novice I'm unable to figure it out on my own...

Thank you for your time and effort! :)

Comment: A command (do) file for stimuli is not part of the VHDL standard  and limits the use of other standard compliant tools while a testbench can be portable. There is a requirement for matching elements between an array target and value expression in an assignment. This [different architecture using a concurrent conditional assignment statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbIuG.jpg) produces no standard mandated error when the testbench is simulated. Your question 1. solicits opinion and is off topic, while there are numerous ways to avoid declaring constant arrays (2.).

Comment: [This meets your modified question criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YokFe.jpg) although I can't help but wonder if your question doesn't involve an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: @user16145658. Thank you for your second answer. Is there any special need to keep 'else' on the line 69, though?

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the function to return a result with the same constraints as the target (most easily done by making a constrained subtype for result and target).

Or if you want to handle different sized assignment targets, the easiest way is to add a size parameter, and pass `target'length` (here `ACT_SET'length`) to that size parameter.

Then simply handle padding or truncation however you wish in the function.

Comment: When a user  might rely on the -2019 return identifier feature in a function specification is not known (where relying on the subtype being defined by context would result in an impure function) the only way to get the length in a pure function would be via a parameter ([which can have a default value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YokFe.jpg)) or a subtype declaration. What isn't clear in the question here is why a function specification would require the return value to have multiple distinct subtypes. Any assignment target object is guaranteed to be fully constrained when elaborated.

Comment: @user1818839. Excellent food for thought. Thank you.